# What is this sound on FM radio?

Tags: receiver

When tuned around 87.5-88 FM, a strange repetitive sound can be heard.

The title ['Les Professionnels' from 'Air'](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MofYHilG2ec&t=10) start with this sound.